# How to show a chrome app's shortcut icon (created by me) next to the address bar on each page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I just created my first chrome app using this tutorial : http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html

I followed all steps and could successfully created my first chrome app, Now this app shortcut appears on the app window : **chrome://apps/**

[image]

I want my apps shortcut to be shown next to the address bar also, next to the settings icon like this

[image]

Is this possible ? I can kind of new to this and have been trying my hand at this. Any suggestions/advice are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do it using `chrome app` for this you have to create an `extension` with `browserAction` go [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)